# Unable to disable Bluetooth

Tags: mac, catalina, bluetooth, menu-bar, system-settings

How can I disable Bluetooth on my MacBook Air?

The option to disable it is greyed out in System Preferences and is non-existent from the Bluetooth menubar. I'm currently using the latest MacOS Catalina update and this has been a problem for quite some time now. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: Menubar]
[image]

Comment: Does Bluetooth still show up in "About my Mac" -> "System report"?  Did you try to create a new admin account on your Mac and toggle it from there? Is your Mac remotely-managed (e.g. as part of a company setup)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "Turn off Bluetooth" using Siri?

I'm not suggesting it will work given the weird behavior you're experiencing, just that it might be worth a try. Maybe her response will provide a hint?

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 3rd party app called [Bluetoggle](http://www.axoniclabs.com/Bluetoggle/#) that lets you set up a hotkey to toggle Bluetooth on and off. Maybe this will enable you to turn it off. The app has a free trial period and if it works you can purchase for $3.00.

There is also a way to turn it off from the command line. Open terminal or iTerm and at the command line type

`blueutil -p 0`

This will turn Bluetooth off.

Comment: `blueutil: command not found`, don't think this is part of macOS. Also how would general Bluetooth tools help to toggle BT if macOS itself can't?